# Why node binary size is way more than pre-build binary while cross compiling to 32 bit ARM

Tags: node.js, arm, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, 32-bit

I am cross compiling node to 32 bit ARM processor.
Using node v12.22.12 source code downloaded from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.22.12/

Using an ubuntu VM to cross compile. not sure how to reduce node binary for embedded system.

Any help/suggestion will be helpful.

I am using following command to create binary.

- processor: ARM
- compiler: pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi enviornment:
- environment-setup-armv7at2-neon-pokymllib32-linux-gnueabi
- CC_host:"gcc -m32"
- CXX_host: "g++ m32"

```
./configure --dest-cpu=arm --cross-compiling --with-arm-float-abi=soft --with-arm-fpu=vfpv3 --without-intl --without-dtrace --without-node-snapshot --without-npm --without-inspector --without-etw 

make -j2 
make install -j2
```

Still I got the binary size around 725 MB which is way more than pre-build binary (~80 mb).

I need to reduce the file size to less than 80 Mb so that it can be used in embedded system. also need openssl as I need https.

Comment: "_too big for embedded system_" is subjecttive - clearly _your_ enbedded system is still _huge_ if 100Mb is small enough.  I am guessing your embedded system is Linux?  You should probably use the [embedded-linux] tag in that case.  The [embedded] tag includes the systems with memory in the order of Kb rather then Mb (probably the majority of embedded systems).  Using [embedded-linux] will get you a more focussed audience with specialist knowledge.

Comment: This https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/42948 may be relevant, but there OP suggests the footprint is much smaller than you have stated by a factor of nearly 10 (Only 80Mb _before_ any minimisation attempts).  The Arm Linux binary binary at https://nodejs.org/en/download is only ~80Mb. so there is something wrong here.  You would do better to use the pre-built binary perhaps?

Comment: @Clifford Agree. 100mb is still big. I want to reduce it to less than 10 mb. thats why I am cross compiling to achieve targeted size. Yes embedded system is Yocto Linux distribution. Somehow using above command in Ubuntu VM generates around ~725 MB. This is my biggest concern.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: So your question should perhaps be about why it is so much larger than the project's pre-built binary.

Comment: Yes, updated title and added more context to make it more understandable.

Comment: Your configuration looks bizarre because it specifies both soft and hard floating-point: `--with-arm-float-abi=soft --with-arm-fpu=vfpv3`.

Comment: @sawdust even removing these configurations and using default setting does not help.  with ```/configure --dest-cpu=arm --cross-compiling --dest-os=linux --without-intl  --without-node-snapshot --without-npm --without-inspector  --without-node-code-cache
```
Size is huge around 728 MB. How can it be more than provided node binary size?

Comment: Start examining what are in these executables and what are their dependencies. Could the huge size be due to static linking? Is there a symbol map from the build? Try using the `ldd` command or the `strings` approach (see the answer to https://superuser.com/questions/1176200/no-such-file-when-it-exists) to see what shared libraries and entrypoints are used. Have you even tried to run these executables on the target board?

Comment: sorry for late replay. was busy in other work. If anybody still wants to know changing cross compiler to arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc significantly reduced the size. current size around 30 MB with additional configurations.